# Can anyone explain what this means

Tags: automation

Can anyone explain to me what this code means?

```
print "Testlauf  --  Zeile: " &    DataTable.GetSheet(dtLocalSheet).GetCurrentRow & "  (" &  DataTable("reg_email", dtLocalSheet) & ")" & "   Zeit: " & now 
print "GP_NachName='" & Environment.value("GP_NachName") & "'"
print "GP2_NachName='" & Environment.value("GP2_NachName") & "'"
print "GP_Hausnummer='" & Environment.value("GP_Hausnummer") & "'"
print "Mail='" & Mail & "'"
```

Comment: I'm thinking the answer is probably:   42?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is printing probably current executing row number and the e-mail ID associated with it.
Second, third, and fourth line are printing a value from Environment Values.
Last line is printing value of the variable Mail.

Let me try to explain in details:

---

```
print "Testlauf  --  Zeile: " &    DataTable.GetSheet(dtLocalSheet).GetCurrentRow & "  (" &  DataTable("reg_email", dtLocalSheet) & ")" & "   Zeit: " & now
```

> Now above code is a bit messy one. the line **DataTable.GetSheet(dtLocalSheet).GetCurrentRow** will print the currently executing now number. 
>   Where as **DataTable("reg_email", dtLocalSheet)** will print the e-mail id stored from that row. 
>   Now **"   Zeit: " & now** will append ***Zeit:*** to the end of the string and **now** will give you current time stamp. So one sample output could be : 
>  
> **Testlauf -- Zeile: 1 test@test.com Zeit : 9/7/2016 12:12:6**

```
print "GP_NachName='" & Environment.value("GP_NachName") & "'"
print "GP2_NachName='" & Environment.value("GP2_NachName") & "'"
print "GP_Hausnummer='" & Environment.value("GP_Hausnummer") & "'"
```

> Above 3 lines will simply print values stored in the environment variables. You could set values in environment variables like : Environment.Value("SampleVar") = "SampleValue" 
>   So a simple output could be: 
>  
>   **GP_NachName = < value of GP_NachName>**

```
print "Mail='" & Mail & "'"
```

> Above line would simple print something like : **Mail = ValueStoredInMail**

Hope that helps. Let me know if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much kumar. It really help. Can i get your email id?